# Tips for GIT versioning Linux RAM Disk Image (ramdisk.gz) contents

Tags: linux, git, ramdisk

I've a Linux RAM DISK Image zipped in ramdisk.gz archive.

I modify the existing RAM disk image mounting it as a loop back device.

```
gunzip ramdisk.gz

mount -o loop ramdisk ramdisk_dir

vi xxxx

umount ramdisk_dir

gzip -9 ramdisk
```

I'd like to GIT version the content of the RAM disk image.

Any tips or recommendations to do it?

Comment: Um, don't? Probably put the _contents_ in version control instead.

Comment: What does it means?

Comment: Storing diffs between two gzipped blobs in Git is crazy, you want to store the unzipped data in Git.